# plotting multiple contour plots on the same figure

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to make multiple contourf plots using the same figure: I want to display each contour as one color and then plot legend for each color

When I try, all the two countours ends up as the same color showing no difference at all

```
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
fig, axarr = plt.subplots( figsize=(10, 8), constrained_layout=True,
                          subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj))
# = axarr.flatten()
# APRIL TO SEPTEMBER
axarr.contourf(lon, lat, pskw, transform=proj, cmap=cm.Blues,)
 axarr.contourf(lon, lat, shift, transform=proj, cmap=cm.Reds,)

This is my code
```

I want to get seperate colors for each contourf in one figure:

Thanks

Comment: Because you set different colormaps to both contours one would expect them to be different. So if this is not the case for you, one needs to see a [mcve] (i.e. runnable code) to find out what problem there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me that both pskw and shift will be plotted on the same nodes, identified by lon and lat. This means that the second contourf call will simply hide the first one.

With this in mind, there are a few possibilities:

- use contourf for the first call and contour for the second one
- determine two non-overlapping parts of your spatial domain and call contourf on each sub-domain for a different variable
- create two subplots and plot each variable in one subplot
- make use of opacity and zorder for the two calls of contourf, but this might get awkward

Comment: Thanks bit I found a way to do it. My data was made up of zeros and ones and all I had to do is mask out the zeros, and then I have my map, Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Thanks, Please my data is from -1 to +1 but I want to set from +0.25 to -0.25 as white the remaiing levels takes different colors. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What if you define a mask: mask = (pskw < - 0.25) & (pskw > 0.25), and you apply it to the variables inside the contourf calls?

Comment: Sure that did work, except that other parts of the colormap gets messed up. Specifically can I devise my own cmap such that from 1-0.5 is red, 0.5-0.25  is blue, 0.25- -0.25 is white, then -0.25- -0.5 green, and last -0.5- -1 is blue? @Patol75

Comment: Have a look here (https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html).

Comment: sure I have already viridis = cm.get_cmap('viridis', 256)
newcolors = viridis(np.linspace(0, 1, 256))
pink = np.array([248/256, 24/256, 148/256, 1])
newcolors[:25, :] = pink
newcmp = ListedColormap(newcolors)  # Can you explain the part that says pink = np.array([248/255,24/255, 148/255,1)] I think 1 there is for opacity but how did they come by those fractions is my confusion now. Thanks

Comment: Opacity, correct. The other three numbers are for the RGB code.